# Toogle en navbar de Freeboard usando Boostrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Como podran ver soy muy novato en frontend, estoy haciendo una modificacion de la plataforma ioT Freeboard le quiero agregar una barra de navegacion con Boostrap y al momento de reducir la pantalla (responsive) el boton de opciones(hamburg) no las despliega. estoy vuelto loco.
He intentado comentar algunos elementos, la navbar funciona bien en modo escritorio pero no funciona correctamente en modo movil.

El rezise de la pantalla si funciona lo unico que no trabaja es el drop down button

[estoy utilizando el navbar de boostrap:](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

la plataforma a modificar es esta: [Freeboard:](https://github.com/Freeboard/freeboard)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>freeboard</title>
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <meta name="viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1, user-scalable = no" />

    <!--bootstrap 4 -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <!--Custom CSS -->
     <link href="css/freeboard.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--<link href="css/freeboard.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
    <script src="js/freeboard.thirdparty.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        head.js("js/freeboard_plugins.min.js",
                "plugins/thirdparty/clearobject.mqtt.plugin.js",
                "plugins/thirdparty/actuator.js",
                "plugins/thirdparty/actuatorMQTT.js",
                "plugins/thirdparty/actuatorMQTTNotSensData.js",
                // *** Load more plugins here ***
                function(){
                    $(function()
                    { //DOM Ready
                        freeboard.initialize(true); //inicializa la interfaz de freeboard
                        let myHeaders = new Headers();
                        let options = {
                          method: 'POST',
                          headers: myHeaders,
                          body: new URLSearchParams({
                            'switchState':"switchState"// si se desean enviar parametros(datos) para validar alguna credencial al iniciar el dashboard
                          }),
                        }
                        let host = '/dash/load';
                        let myRequest = new Request(host, options);
                        fetch(myRequest, {credentials: 'include'})
                          .then((res) => {
                            if(res.ok) {//Si hay repuesta
                              console.log('Ok');
                              return res.json(); // <- parseamos la respuesta y lo devolvemos a nuestra función
                            }else{// Si no hay respuesta del servidor
                              console.log('No response');
                            }
                          })
                          .then((resParsed) => {
//                            console.log("Json: " + resParsed)
                            if(resParsed  !== null){//Si hay datos del dashboard en el JSON
                              var jsonObject = JSON.parse(resParsed);
 //                             console.log(jsonObject); // <- mostramos los datos recibidos
                              freeboard.loadDashboard(jsonObject, function() {
                                  freeboard.setEditing(false);
                              });
                            }else{//Si la respuesta es NULL por parte del servidor ******Abre el archivo del dasboard de ejemplo
                              console.log('Now you dont have a dasboard on cloud, but we have an example: ');
                              var hashpattern = window.location.hash.match(/(&|#)source=([^&]+)/);//extrae la direccion del archivo de ejemplo
                              if (hashpattern !== null) {//Si hay direccion carga el archivo
                                  $.getJSON(hashpattern[2], function(data) {
                                      freeboard.loadDashboard(data, function() {
                                          freeboard.setEditing(false);
                                      });
                                  });
                              }
                            }
                          })
                          options = {
                          method: 'GET',
                          headers: myHeaders,
                        }
                        host = '/dash/user_data';
                        let myRequest2 = new Request(host, options);
                        fetch(myRequest2, {credentials: 'include'})
                          .then((res) => {
                            if(res.ok) {//Si hay repuesta
                              console.log('Okey');
                              return res.json(); // <- parseamos la respuesta y lo devolvemos a nuestra función
                            }else{// Si no hay respuesta del servidor
                              console.log('No response');
                            }
                          })
                          .then((resParsed) => {
                            console.log("Json: ", resParsed.username)
                            if(resParsed  !== null){//Si hay datos del dashboard en el JSON
//                              var jsonObject = JSON.parse(resParsed);
//                              console.log("jsonObject: ",jsonObject); // <- mostramos los datos recibidos
                              
                            }else{//Si la respuesta es NULL por parte del servidor ******Abre el archivo del dasboard de ejemplo
                              console.log('Now you dont have a dasboard on cloud, but we have an example: ');
                              
                            }
                          })




                    });
                }
              );


    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!--  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Notes App</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/">{{user.name}}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
                </ul>
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">




                    <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/users/logout">Logout</a>
                </li>


          </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
-->
<div id = "navigation"> </div>

<div id="board-content">
    <img id="dash-logo" data-bind="attr:{src: header_image}, visible:header_image()">
    <div class="gridster responsive-column-width">
        <ul data-bind="grid: true">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<header id="main-header" data-bind="if:allow_edit">
<!--    <div id="admin-bar">
        <div id="admin-menu">
            <div id="board-tools">
                <h1 id="board-logo" class="title bordered">freeboard</h1>
                <div id="board-actions">
                    <ul class="board-toolbar vertical">
                        <li data-bind="click: loadDashboardFromLocalFile"><i id="full-screen-icon" class="icon-folder-open icon-white"></i><label id="full-screen">Load Freeboard</label></li>
                        <li onclick="loadDashboardClickedCloud()" id = "loadOnCloud"><i id="full-screen-icon" class="fas fa-cloud-download-alt icon-white"></i><label id="full-screen">Load from cloud </label></li>
                        <li onclick="saveDashboardClickedCloud()" id = "saveOnCloud"><i id="full-screen-icon" class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt icon-white"></i><label id="full-screen">save on cloud </label></li>
                        <li><i class="icon-download-alt icon-white"></i>

                            <label data-bind="click: saveDashboardClicked">Save Freeboard</label>
                            <label style="display: none;" data-bind="click: saveDashboard" data-pretty="true">[Pretty]</label>
                            <label style="display: none;" data-bind="click: saveDashboard" data-pretty="false">[Minified]</label>
                        </li>
                        <li id="add-pane" data-bind="click: createPane"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i><label>Add Pane</label></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="datasources">
                <h2 class="title">DATASOURCES</h2>

                <div class="datasource-list-container">
                    <table class="table table-condensed sub-table" id="datasources-list" data-bind="if: datasources().length">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Last Updated</th>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: datasources">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span class="text-button datasource-name" data-bind="text: name, pluginEditor: {operation: 'edit', type: 'datasource'}"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td data-bind="text: last_updated"></td>
                            <td>
                                <ul class="board-toolbar">
                                    <li data-bind="click: updateNow"><i class="icon-refresh icon-white"></i></li>
                                    <li data-bind="pluginEditor: {operation: 'delete', type: 'datasource'}">
                                        <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i></li>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <span class="text-button table-operation" data-bind="pluginEditor: {operation: 'add', type: 'datasource'}">ADD</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    --> 
    <!--
    <div id="column-tools" class="responsive-column-width">
        <ul class="board-toolbar left-columns">
            <li class="column-tool add" data-bind="click: addGridColumnLeft"><span class="column-icon right"></span><i class="icon-arrow-left icon-white"></i></li>
            <li class="column-tool sub" data-bind="click: subGridColumnLeft"><span class="column-icon left"></span><i class="icon-arrow-right icon-white"></i></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="board-toolbar right-columns">
            <li class="column-tool sub" data-bind="click: subGridColumnRight"><span class="column-icon right"></span><i class="icon-arrow-left icon-white"></i></li>
            <li class="column-tool add" data-bind="click: addGridColumnRight"><span class="column-icon left"></span><i class="icon-arrow-right icon-white"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="toggle-header" data-bind="click: toggleEditing">
        <i id="toggle-header-icon" class="icon-wrench icon-white"></i></div>
    -->
</header>

<div style="display:hidden">
    <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'pane-template', foreach: panes}">
    </ul>
</div>

<input type="text" style="display: none" id="refreshed" value="no">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //Barra de Navegacion
   //let user = {name:"pepon"}; //simula un logeado
    let user = ""; // simula cliente no logeado
 
      let izq = `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Notes App </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
           <a class="nav-link" href="/"> Home <span class="sr-only"> (current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">`
      let ifuser =  `<li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/dashboard">DashBoard </a>
            </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                     <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                         Notes
                     </a>
                     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                         <a class="dropdown-item" href="/notes">All notes </a>
                         <a class="dropdown-item" href="/notes/add">Add Note </a>
                         <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                         <a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/logout">Logout </a>
                     </div>
                </li>`
      let ifnouser = `              <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/users/signinval">SignIn </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/users/signupval">SignUp </a>
                </li>`
      let end = ` </ul>
              </div>

                  </div>
                    </nav>`

    if(user){
     document.getElementById('navigation').innerHTML = izq + ifuser + end;
    }else{
     document.getElementById('navigation').innerHTML = izq + ifnouser + end;
    }
  /*funcion para refrescar el dashboard cuando se da logOut y se intenta regresar
    con el boton atras del navegador*/
/*
      onload = function () {
         var e = document.getElementById("refreshed");
         if (e.value == "no")
             e.value = "yes";
         else {
               e.value = "no";
               location.reload();
         }
     }
*/
   </script>

<script type="text/html" id="pane-template">
    <li data-bind="pane: true">
        <header>
            <h1 data-bind="text: title"></h1>
            <ul class="board-toolbar pane-tools">
                <li data-bind="pluginEditor: {operation: 'add', type: 'widget'}">
                    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                </li>
                <li data-bind="pluginEditor: {operation: 'edit', type: 'pane'}">
                    <i class="icon-wrench icon-white"></i>
                </li>
                <li data-bind="pluginEditor: {operation: 'delete', type: 'pane'}">
                    <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <section data-bind="foreach: widgets">
            <div class="sub-section" data-bind="css: 'sub-section-height-' + height()">
                <div class="widget" data-bind="widget: true, css:{fillsize:fillSize}"></div>
                <div class="sub-section-tools">
                    <ul class="board-toolbar">
                        <!-- ko if:$parent.widgetCanMoveUp($data) -->
                        <li data-bind="click:$parent.moveWidgetUp"><i class="icon-chevron-up icon-white"></i></li>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- ko if:$parent.widgetCanMoveDown($data) -->
                        <li data-bind="click:$parent.moveWidgetDown"><i class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></i></li>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <li data-bind="pluginEditor: {operation: 'edit', type: 'widget'}"><i class="icon-wrench icon-white"></i></li>
                        <li data-bind="pluginEditor: {operation: 'delete', type: 'widget'}"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </li>
</script>
<script>
function saveDashboardClickedCloud() {
  //var x = document.getElementById("saveOnCloud");
  //x.disabled = true;
  //alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
freeboard.showLoadingIndicator(true);
var Dashjson = JSON.stringify(freeboard.serialize());
console.log('Desde IndexDasboard: '+ Dashjson);
//post('/dash/save', {stringDash: Dashjson});

let myHeaders = new Headers();

fetch('/dash/save', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: new URLSearchParams({stringDash: Dashjson}),
})
.then((res) => {
  if(res.ok) {
    console.log('Ok');
    freeboard.setEditing(false);
    freeboard.showLoadingIndicator(false);
  //  return res.json(); // <- parseamos el response y lo devolvemos a nuestra función
  }else{
    console.log('No data recived')
  }
})


}
/*
function post(path, params, method='post') {

     //* sends a request to the specified url from a form. this will change the window location.
     //* @param {string} path the path to send the post request to
     //* @param {object} params the paramiters to add to the url
    // * @param {string} [method=post] the method to use on the form


    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    const form = document.createElement('form');
    form.method = method;
    form.action = path;

    for (const key in params) {
      if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenField.type = 'hidden';
        hiddenField.name = key;
        hiddenField.value = params[key];

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
    console.log('Enviado');
}
*/
function loadDashboardClickedCloud() {
//  var x = document.getElementById("loadOnCloud");
  //x.disabled = true;
  //alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
//var Dashjson = JSON.stringify(freeboard.serialize());
//console.log('Desde IndexDasboard: '+ Dashjson);
//post('/dash/save', {stringDash: Dashjson});


freeboard.showLoadingIndicator(true);
let myHeaders = new Headers();

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: new URLSearchParams({
    'switchState':"switchState"
  }),
}
const host = '/dash/load';
let myRequest = new Request(host, options);
fetch(myRequest, {credentials: 'include'})
  .then((res) => {
    if(res.ok) {
      console.log('Ok');
      return res.json(); // <- parseamos el response y lo devolvemos a nuestra función
    }

  })
  .then((resParsed) => {
    if(resParsed  !== null){//Si hay datos del dashboard en el JSON recibido mediante POST
      var jsonObject = JSON.parse(resParsed);
      console.log(jsonObject); // <- mostramos los datos recibidos
      freeboard.loadDashboard(jsonObject, function() {
          freeboard.setEditing(false);
          freeboard.showLoadingIndicator(false);
      });
  }else{
      //alert("Now you dont have a saved Dasboard on cloud!");    //
      freeboard.showLoadingIndicator(false);
      freeboard.showDialog($("<div align='center'>Now you dont have a saved Dasboard on cloud!</div>"),"No prblem!","OK",null,function(){});
  }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Debes incluir el código que te genera problemas para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Agregado... donde posiblemente este el problema es el div id="navigation" y el js que agrega o no el html de la navbar, segun la variable user. Gracias por tu respuesta, aun  no encuentro el problema

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tenia estaba en los enlaces de Boostrap y Jquery que usa Freeboard y el HTML a modificar, quedaria de la siguiente forma por si a alguien le sucede:

```
...
    <meta name="viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1, user-scalable = no" />

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- FONT AWESOME -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <!--Custom CSS -->
...

...
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

}

</script>
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```